Is there a way to include a package in unattended upgrades when only security upgrades are enabled?
I like to know how exactly the mechanism works that selects a package as security to install it.
I am also interested if that can happen with a 3rd party package.
By default, all Ubuntu packages are already configured as part of the packages that are selected for auto updates. BUT only security updates are actually made because of my settings. I am trying to understand how it selects packages as security packages.
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    ...
}

It is my understanding, the file for a package from a 3rd party repo in /var/lib/apt/lists need to have a Origin: defined to be able to use Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern. I was trying this with Brave, and it sadly does not have Origin: there, but assuming there is one for a different package I like to know how it would work if not all unattended upgrades are enabled but just security updates.
AI tells me I should do apt-cache policy firefox to check if a package is marked as a security package, and I see that my Firefox package is currently NOT set as security. But it not basically every new browser version a security update? I guess not but Ubuntu standards. At least based on the example AI gives me.
firefox:
  Installed: 1.2.3-4
  Candidate: 1.2.3-4
  Version table:
     1.2.3-4 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.2-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

For me, it just shows oracular/main not -security.
// Firefox is probably a very bad example, actually. As I think this is just some dummy package on modern Ubuntu's. Firefox is by default a snap package and updated daily by default with snap I believe.
But is it just the security or -security string in the origin that determines what is a security package? Or is it like hardcoded that only packages from the official security apt origin are considered security packages for unattended-updates. Can a 3rd party packages be a security package?

@user68186 You seem to not have read "the unofficial Brave repo" I am aware it's not an official repo. I was asking specifically how security updates are detected. So it's not a duplicate. I am also asking for the exact code for brave. You trigger-happy people on this site trying to mark every question as dupe really pisses me off. If a take hour to figure out the right origin or whatever, and then only to find out that would only work if I have unattended updates set to all. It would be a waste. I clearly described in the title and the question it about the security distinction how that works

@user68186 You have repeated multiple things back to me that I already knew and in fact spelled out in the question. You do not know the answers you "think" is not good enough. So you vote to delete that shitty behavior on your part. I already found out the brave sources have no Origin: as I understand it now, I can basically forget it or write my own script to do it.

But I still do care about the actual answer to this. I want not make it about Brave specifically anymore, I want to know what exact mechanism it is that determines if a package is considered security, how that entire mechanic works. And that is NOT answered in that question you so desperately want to mark as a dupe.

Then you should edit your question and make it about what you want to be about. Only Canonical may answer what you seem to be asking. They are not here. Or are you seeking the opinion of other users?

"I see that my Firefox package is currently NOT set as security." Your output shows the installed version is the version from focal-security

You really can not read! TikTok brain or something? That is not my output, that is example output AI gave me. READ what is written below that, and above for that matter.
